# Ruby on Rails: Nested join query issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an issue with getting a nested join to work properly.

My table is something like: |id|type|some_data|parent_id|

This table is then defined in Rails like so:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Type1 < Table
  has_many :type2s, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: Type2
end

class Type2 < Table
  has_many :type3s, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: Type3
  belongs_to :type1, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: Type1
end

class Type3 < Table
  belongs_to :type2, class_name: Type2, foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

I am attempting to get Type1 values based on the input of Type3. So

```
Type1.joins(type2s: :type3s).where(type3s: { id: type3s_ids })
```

But the query that is generating seems to hardcode "type3s"."id" in (...), while aliasing Table to type3_SCHEMA_TABLE. For example:

```
SELECT "SCHEMA"."TABLE".* FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE" 
INNER JOIN "SCHEMA"."TABLE" "type1_SCHEMA_TABLE" ON "type1_SCHEMA_TABLE"."PARENT_ID" = "SCHEMA"."TABLE"."ID" AND "type1_SCHEMA_TABLE"."TYPE" IN ('Type1')
INNER JOIN "SCHEMA"."TABLE" "type2_SCHEMA_TABLE" ON "type2_SCHEMA_TABLE"."PARENT_ID" = "type1_SCHEMA_TABLE"."ID" AND "type2_SCHEMA_TABLE"."TYPE" IN ('Type2')
INNER JOIN "SCHEMA"."TABLE" "type3_SCHEMA_TABLE" ON "type3_SCHEMA_TABLE"."PARENT_ID" = "type2_SCHEMA_TABLE"."ID" AND "type2_SCHEMA_TABLE"."TYPE" IN ('Type3') AND "TYPE3S"."ID" IN (...);
```

As you can see from above, the query generated is using "TYPE3S"."ID" instead of "type3_SCHEMA_TABLE"."ID".

I'm also experiencing the same thing if I try to do:
    Type1.joins(:type2s).where(type2s: { id: ... })

Oddly:

```
Type1.first.type2s #<< works
Type2.first.type3s #<< works
Type3.first.type2 # << works
Type3.first.type2.type1 # << works
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: It sounds like what your attempting is single-table inheritance with self joins? Can you show, for a single active record query (1) what SQL it generates, and (2) what SQL you are hoping to generate?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this table is. (1) The SQL generated is like the SQL posted above. (Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.) (2) The query I'd like ultimately is something like: SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE" a JOIN "SCHEMA"."TABLE" b ON b.parent_id = a.id JOIN "SCHEMA"."TABLE" c ON c.parent_id = b.id;

Comment: Try `Type1.joins(type2s:  :type3s).where(type2s: { type3s: { id: type3s_ids } })`

Comment: @TomAranda: I guess I should've mentioned that I tried that too. When I do that it appears to try and compare type2s.id to an Arel ruby object. :-/